# AWS EC2 Import/Export service Linux

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Has anyone had success with the AWS Import/Export service particularly with the Linux machine?

I have tried to import/convert Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit with 1 disk machines. All these virtual machines were p2v converted by using MondoRescue and are running perfectly well. I ended up with this: "...We have detected a problem with this task. A technician will take a look at the issue within 24 hours..." With no feedback from AWS technician.

I believe that my machines meet AWS 'Requirements and Limitations' for the Linux machines: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/VMImportPrerequisites.html

My p2v machines are Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit with 1 disk. The disk is partitioned (/dev/sda1 - /, /dev/sda5 - data, /dev/sda6 - swap). I have tried to no avail the following options:
1. VM with the mounted sda5
2. VM with unmounted (not mounted) sda5
3. VM with deleted sda5
All these p2v- MondoRescue virtual machines are running perfectly well (VMware).
post-Migration (p2v) configuration changes: **fstab, grub, interfaces, 70-persistent-net.rules** to reflect a new virtual environment.
I didn't use UUID on all my machines, all partitions are mounted as /dev/sda ...
I think that the AWS conversion task checks if the initrd contains necessary modules and if not it builds a new initrd containing them. Is this the point of failure?

All import tasks have been launched by:
**ec2-import-instance -t m3.medium -f VHD -a x86_64 -p Linux -b somebucket -z us-east-1b** ...

VHD - because ec2-import-instance couldn't process VMDK (some not supported compression algorithm. AWS: "...you can only import VMDK files into Amazon EC2 that were created through the OVF export process in VMware..."), so I converted VMDK to VHD (growable) by using StarWind V2V converter. I have tested all my VHDs locally and they worked without errors (VM creation on the base of the existing disk, in my case, VHDs). So I can rule out any VMDK to VHD conversion problems.

There is no way (at least I do not know of any) to access the AWS import/conversion task log file, so it is not possible for users to find out what caused the conversion task failure.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out my problems with Ubuntu machines were caused by the grub2. I have reverted the grub2 to the legacy grub 0.97 and it worked out for me. IMHO, it is time to begin a grub2 support.
I work only with Ubuntu machines so I can't state that my solution is for all supported by AWS distros.  The 'VM Import/Export Prerequisites' document http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/VMImportPrerequisites.html doesn't mention anything about grub requirements.